# How to find integrals including certain expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

how do I find some terms in an integral containing some expression, e.g. in

$$
\int \int \int \beta\phi(x,y,z) + \gamma\omega(x,y,z)\,\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y \textrm{d}z +\int \int \alpha\phi(x,y,z) + \gamma\theta(x,y,z)\,\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y
$$

only the term including $\phi(x,y,z)$ (incl. integrals), meaning:

$$
\int \int \int \beta\phi(x,y,z) \textrm{d}x  \textrm{d}y \textrm{d}z +\int \int \alpha\phi(x,y,z) \textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y\quad?
$$

The approaches I found online so far don't work, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What approaches have you tried? What is the problem with the code you’re using? Is this a question about the software *Mathematica*? You can get help with a  mathematics problem at http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I meant how do I achieve this with _Mathematica_? I've tried different approaches with _Select_, _MemberQ_, _Coefficient_, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
(int1 = Integrate[β ϕ[x, y, z] + γ ω[x, y, z], z, y, x] +
    Integrate[α ϕ[x, y, z] + γ θ[x, y, z], y, x]) //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(int2 = int1 /. {_ω :> 0, _θ :> 0}) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Or

```
(int3 = int1 /. 
    Integrate[a_*phi_ϕ + b___, var__] :> 
     Integrate[a*phi, var]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
int2 === int3

(* True *)
```

Comment: This unfortunately is not what I meant, as I don't actually know what the other terms look like - $\omega$ and $\Theta$ were just placeholders.